# has ms sqlserver data vault feature?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005, oracle

as far as i know oracle has the "DATA VAULT" feature.so has sql server?if it has,give me an information link about that feature please.

```
* Preventing highly privileged users (DBA) from accessing application data
* Enforcing separation of duty
* Providing controls over who, when, where and how applications, data and databases can be accessed.
```

http://www.oracle.com/technology/deploy/security/database-security/database-vault/index.html

Comment: its also considered polite to mark your questions answered when someone gives you a satisfactory answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Sql server can encrypt data,](http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2009/04/28/sql-server-introduction-to-sql-server-encryption-and-symmetric-key-encryption-tutorial-with-script/) and [it has a very fine-grained ACL model.](http://www.databasejournal.com/features/mssql/article.php/3713116/SQL-Server-Security-Model.htm). What specific security and auditing features are you looking for ?

-- edit --

SQL server has a master superuser 'sa', however roles can be created with restricted administrative privileges.

From your link :

> - Providing controls over who, when, where and how applications, data and databases can be accessed.

I can't say anything about the 'when' in terms of how the ACL's are modelled [1](http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2009/04/28/sql-server-introduction-to-sql-server-encryption-and-symmetric-key-encryption-tutorial-with-script/). But the when, where and what can be modelled.

[1](http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2009/04/28/sql-server-introduction-to-sql-server-encryption-and-symmetric-key-encryption-tutorial-with-script/) Does someone know if time can be represented in the ACL models ?

Comment: Nothing through SQL 2005 allows login enabling/disabling by time (unless you modify access rights via scheduled jobs, which sounds like a pretty poor idea). I haven't heard of SQL 2008 doing this, either.

Comment: Yeah, thought so, and besides I think that stuff should go into application logic if you ask me.